# IMagemagick's DrawAnnotation doesn't appear to work on Amazon's Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, imagemagick

I am using Python's wand 0.2.2 to access ImageMagick 6.5.4-7. I am trying to apply some text to some photos. I had to extend wand 0.2.2 a bit, but I got it working on Windows. My python code is as follows:

```
color = image.Pixel()
color.color = 'white'
draw = image.Draw()
draw.font = 'verdana'
draw.fontsize = font_size
draw.fillcolor = color
draw.annotation(dx, dy, watermark_text)
new_image = image.Image(width=pic.width, height=pic.height)
new_image.DrawImage(draw)
```

On my Amazon linux instance, I installed the msttcorefonts. If I do

```
identify -list font
```

I get a list of fonts that includes verdana. If I run:

```
convert -font verdana label:foo foo.gif
```

I get an image that has verdana text.

Everything looks good, until I execute my code and I get no text on my picture.
The python code works fine on Windows, and as far as I can tell imagemagick can find the font on my linux box. It just refuses to place the text on the picture.

I've tried "verdana," "Verdana-Regular", and the full path to the ttf '/usr.../verdana.ttf'. I even tried other fonts that are installed on the system. The draw code is working, if I add "draw.circle..." then a circle will be drawn on my image.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it on *Amazon* where your IM version is 6.5.4-7?

Comment: Yes. It looks like my Windows version of IM is 6.7. I am using the Amazon Linux and that was the IM the repository had.